# C++ template specializations not working with nested types

Tags: c++, templates, nested-types

The following code compiles, but will not work:

```
template<typename T>
struct Nesting
{
    template<typename U>
    struct _Nested
    {
    };

    template<typename U>
    using Nested = _Nested<U>;
};

template<typename T>
struct F
{
    static constexpr bool is_my_nested_class = false;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
struct F<typename Nesting<T>::Nested<U>>
{
    static constexpr bool is_my_nested_class = true;
};
```

I create these Nesting and Nested types and try to uses a type trait pattern on it. It compiles (using MSVC 2014 w/ CPP11), but

```
F<Nesting<int>::Nested<long>>::is_my_nested_class
```

returns *false*.

**Is this forbidden or undefined by the standard ? What rule does it break ? Any workaround ?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm pretty convinced that `T` in  `struct F<typename Nesting<T>::Nested<U>>` is in non-deducable context as such compiler cannot establish both `T` and `U` when passed a type in template instantiation

Comment: `struct F<typename Nesting<T>::Nested<U>>` should I think be `struct F<typename Nesting<T>::template Nested<U>>`. Then, clang 4.0 gives: `error: class template partial specialization contains template parameters that cannot be deduced; this partial specialization will never be used`

Comment: Thanks to your help, I modified F so that the argument T is given instead of being (failing to be) deduced. Without the type alias, it tells me that U cannot be deduced. If I provide both parameters to F (not deduced), it works fine. Thank you very much, I think I understand the problem :) I also find interesting the fact that if Nesting is a non-template type, then U is deduced. There is probably some basic concepts I don't grasp yet, here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested alias could refer to any type, particularly in a specialisation:

```
template<typename T>
struct Nesting
{
    template<typename U>
    struct _Nested
    {
    };

    template<typename U>
    using Nested = _Nested<U>;
};

// Consider this specialisation:
template<>
struct Nesting<int>
{
    template<typename U>
    using Nested = float;
};
```

Now, clearly `F<Nesting<int>::Nested<int>>::is_my_nested_class` should be the same as `F<float>::is_my_nested_class`, however, how can the compiler deduce this for the latter case? That is, if I wrote:

```
static_assert(F<float>::is_my_nested_class, "not nested");
```

The compiler would need to see that `F<float>` is the same as `F<Nesting<int>::Nested<int>>`, even though the latter hasn't been instantiated. As it can't reasonably be expected to do so, the case is disallowed.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer!
My problem is probably that I've no idea of how the compiler deduces the type for the simple F<float>::is_my_nested_class case.

Is the type alias resolved after the template type deduction ?
Would it work if I get rid of the type alias ?

Comment: Your comment is very helpful! Thank you! (So, no it would not solve anything to get rid of the type alias :) )

Comment: @Michel, right, it doesn't help if you get rid of the type alias, because a specialisation of the outer template might re-introduce a type alias anyway. Essentially the practical issue is that the identity of the inner type is dependent on the outer type, which can be specialised.